# Display and Control 2 Views at once

Tags: ios, ios5

Is there any possible way to display another view in a subview of current view and access its controls and current view controls, both on same page. My Target is to divide screen to upper half and lower half where upper half screen changes(different Views on Scroll), and lower half is constant the current view?

Comment: Could you please share a link, or do some explaination to enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me guess upper view is controlled by current controller while the lower one is controlled by sub Controller?
if it is like this you can work like this

```
 //in the current view controller named as currentVC, add the other viewController

 TheOtherViewContrller *controller = [....];

 controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,currentVC.size.height/2,currentVC.size.width/2,currentVC.size.height/2);

 //this is add a child view contrller to controll the other view controller!

 [currentVC addChildViewContrller:controller];
 [currentVC.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

see if this could help:).

Comment: working fine? it's just like adding a controller's view which is belong to its and controlled by it but want it to show in your view.haha:)

Comment: Thank you very much, working fine. cant vote up no reputation for me!!